# If $T$ is $\kappa$-stable, then $|T|\leqslant\kappa$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have heard that if $T$ is a $\kappa$-stable theory (say over a language $\mathcal{L}$), then there is an $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T'$ such that $|T'|\leqslant\kappa$ and $T'\models T$. I think I have a proof of this as follows:

Denote the constant symbols of $\mathcal{L}$ by $C$. First note that we can assume distinct symbols of $C$ are distinct modulo $T$. (Indeed, given any $c,d\in C$ distinct constant symbols, if $T\models c=d$ then we can replace every instance of $d$ in a sentence of $T$ by $c$ and so have that $T\upharpoonright_{\mathcal{L}\setminus\{d\}}\models T$.)

Now note that we may suppose $|C|\leqslant\kappa$. Indeed, for any $c\neq d\in C$, by the above we have that $\text{tp}(c)\neq\text{tp}(d)\in \text{S}_1(T)$, and so $|C|>\kappa$ would contradict $\kappa$-stability of $T$.

Indeed, because $T$ is $\kappa$-stable, we have that $|\text{S}_1(T)|\leqslant\kappa$. For any $p\neq q\in\text{S}_1(T)$, choose $\varphi_{p,q}(v)$ an $\mathcal{L}$-formula such that $\varphi_{p,q}\in p$ and $\neg\varphi_{p,q}\in q$. We claim that any $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\psi(v)$ consistent with $T$ is equivalent to a boolean combination of finitely many of the $\varphi_{p,q}(v)$.

Indeed, for any $r(v)\in\text{S}_1(T)$ such that $\psi\in r$, let $\Sigma_r(v)=\{\varphi_{r,q}\}_{q\neq r\in\text{S}_1(T)}$. We claim $\Sigma_r(v)\models\psi(v)$. If not, then $\Sigma_r(v)\cup\{\neg\psi(v)\}$ is consistent and so is contained in some complete type $s\in\text{S}_1(T)$. Note that $r\neq s$ as the former contains $\psi$ and the latter contains $\neg\psi$, and so we have $\varphi_{r,s}\in\Sigma_r(v)$. However, by construction $\Sigma_r(v)\subseteq s$, so this would mean $\varphi_{r,s}\in s$, a contradiction. Thus indeed $\Sigma_r(v)\models\psi(v)$ and so by compactness there is a finite subset $\Delta_r(v)\subseteq\Sigma_r(v)$ such that $\Delta_r(v)\models\psi(v)$. For each $r\ni\psi$, let $\theta_r(v)=\bigwedge\Delta_r$, so that $\theta_r\in r$, $\theta_r\models\psi$, and $\theta_r$ is a conjunction of (finitely many of) the $\varphi_{r,q}$.

Now we claim that $\{\neg\theta_r\}_{r\ni\psi}\models\neg\psi$. Indeed, if not, then $\{\neg\theta_r\}_{r\ni\psi}\cup\{\psi\}$ would be consistent and hence contained in a complete type $t\in\text{S}_1(T)$. But then $t\ni\psi$, so we would have $\theta_t\in t$ and $\neg\theta_t\in t$, a contradiction. Thus indeed $\{\neg\theta_r\}_{r\ni\psi}\models\neg\psi$, and so again by compactness there are $r_1,\dots,r_k\in \text{S}_1(T)$ such that $\{\neg\theta_{r_i}\}_{i=1}^k\models\neg\psi$. Let $\theta=\bigvee_{i=1}^k\theta_{r_i}$. Then $\neg\theta\models\neg\psi$, so by contraposition $\psi\models\theta$, and also each $\theta_{r_i}\models\psi$, so $\theta\models\psi$, and so $\psi$ is logically equivalent to $\theta$. In addition, each $\theta_{r_i}$ is a conjunction of finitely many $\varphi_{r,q}$, and so $\theta$ is a boolean combination of (finitely many of) the $\varphi_{p,q}$, as desired.

Now, $T\subset\{\psi(c):c\in C,\psi\text{ an }\mathcal{L}\text{-formula}\}$. Hence, letting $T'=\{\varphi_{p,q}(c):c\in C,p\neq q\in\text{S}_1(T), T\models\varphi_{p,q}(c)\}$, the above argument shows that $T'\models T$. Also, $|C|\leqslant\kappa$, and – since $|\text{S}_1(T)|\leqslant\kappa$ – also $|\{\varphi_{p,q}\}_{p\neq q\in\text{S}_1(T)}|\leqslant\kappa$, so $|T'|\leqslant\kappa$ as desired.

So, I have two questions – first, is this proof correct? Second, is there a quicker way of seeing this result? The condition that $|\text{S}_1(T)|\leqslant\kappa$ seems to me to be much weaker that $\kappa$-stability, so I feel like there should be a more immediate way of seeing this result that doesn't involve fiddling around with constant symbols, etc. Can we use the strength of full $\kappa$-stability somehow?

**Edit**: I think I have found a hole in my argument; in paragraph 5, I think the fact that $\Sigma_r(v)\cup\{\neg\psi(v)\}$ is consistent does *not* necessarily mean it is contained in an element of $\text{S}_1(T)$, for which we need also the condition that $\Sigma(v)\cup\{\neg\psi(v)\}$ is consistent with $T$. (For instance, if $\psi(v)$ is actually a sentence (so that the variable $v$ does not appear (free) in it) then $\neg\psi$ will never be consistent with $T$ by the assumption that $T$ is complete and that $\psi$ is consistent with $T$.) Is there a way to fix this hole? Note that the cases where $\psi(v)$ is a sentence are actually very important, as they are the only way to account for those sentences of $T$ that contain no constant symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the thing you're trying to prove is not true (althought the slogan "If $T$ is $\kappa$-stable, then $|T|\leq \kappa$" is essentially correct - see below the horizontal line for a way to make this precise).

For a counterexample, consider a language with $\aleph_1$-many constant symbols $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha<\aleph_1\}$ and the theory which says there are at least two elements in the domain and all the constants are equal: $T = \{\exists x\exists y\, x\neq y\}\cup \{c_\alpha = c_{\beta}\mid \alpha,\beta<\aleph_1\}$. Then $T$ is $\aleph_0$-stable, but $T$ is not axiomatizable by a countable set of sentences. If $|T'| = \aleph_0$, then $T'$ only mentions countably many constant symbols. Picking two constant symbols $c_\alpha$ and $c_\beta$ which are not mentioned in $T'$, we can find a model of $T'$ in which $c_\alpha\neq c_\beta$ by taking an arbitrary model of $T'$ and changing it to interpret $c_\alpha$ and $c_\beta$ to be two distinct elements of the domain. So  $T'\not\models T$.

This issue crops up in the first paragraph of your proposed proof: You say that if $c$ and $d$ are constants such that $T\models c = d$, then letting $T'$ be the theory obtained by replacing $d$ by $c$ everywhere, we have $T'\restriction_{\mathcal{L}\setminus \{d\}}\models T$. But that's not true, because in a model of $T'\restriction_{\mathcal{L}\setminus \{d\}}$, we can interpret the constant $d$ as any element, not necessarily $c$, so  $T'\restriction_{\mathcal{L}\setminus \{c\}}\not\models c = d$.

Also, as you note in the edit, what you've really proved in the fourth and fifth paragraphs of the proof is that there is a finite subset $\Delta(v)\subseteq  \Sigma(v)$ such that  $T\cup \Delta(v)\models \psi(v)$. What happens in the type space $S_1(T)$ is all happening modulo $T$, so the idea of focusing on the type space in one variable and then thinking of sentences in $T$ as formulas in one free variable isn't going to get you anywhere - any sentence in $T$ will automatically be in every type in $S_1(T)$, otherwise the type wouldn't be consistent with $T$! But actually, your idea of separating types and seeing that a small set of formulas suffice to define arbitrary formulas is on the right track... once you clarify what it is you should be trying to prove.

---

The correct statement is this: If an $L$-theory $T$ is $\kappa$-stable (in fact, $|S_n(T)|\leq \kappa$ for all $n$ is enough), then $T$ is a *definitional expansion* of an $L'$-theory $T'$ with $|L'|\leq \kappa$ (and this implies $|T'|\leq \kappa$). We can't hope to have $T'\models T$ in general, but still $T'$ is essentially the same as $T$.

*Lemma:* Suppose $\Delta$ is a set of $L$-formulas in $n$ free variables which is closed under finite Boolean combinations, and such that for any types $p\neq q$ in $S_n(T)$, there exists $\varphi\in \Delta$ such that $\varphi\in p$ and $\lnot \varphi\in q$. Then every $L$-formula in $n$ free variables is equivalent modulo $T$ to a formula in $\Delta$.

You can prove the lemma with two applications of the compactness theorem, along the lines of your attempted proof. But, for fun, here's a fancier topological proof. The formulas in $\Delta$ generate a Hausdorff topology on $S_n(T)$ which is coarser than the usual topology. If a Hausdorff topology on a set $X$ is coarser than a compact topology on $X$, then these topologies are equal. So $\Delta$ in fact generates the standard topology on $S_n(T)$. But in a Stone space (compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected) with a fixed clopen basis, every clopen set is a finite Boolean combination of the elements of the basis.

Ok, now let's fix $n$. For each pair $p\neq q$ in $S_n(T)$, let $\varphi_{p,q}$ be a formula distinguishing these types, and let $\Delta_n = \{\varphi_{p,q}\mid p\neq q\}$. By the Lemma, every formula in $n$ free variables is equivalent modulo $T$ to a finite Boolean combination of the formulas in $\Delta_n$.

Let $\Delta = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} \Delta_n$, and let $L'$ consist of all symbols in $L$ which appear in some formula in $\Delta$. Since $|S_n(T)| \leq \kappa$,  $|\Delta_n| \leq \kappa$, for all $n$, so $|\Delta|\leq \kappa$, and hence $|L'|\leq \kappa$.

For each $n$-ary relation symbol $R$ in $L\setminus L'$,  the formula $R(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is equivalent modulo $T$ to a finite Boolean combination of formulas in $\Delta_n$, so it is definable by an $L'$-formula $\psi_R(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Similarly, for every $n$-ary function symbol $f$, $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_{n+1}$ is definable by an $L'$-formula $\psi_f(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})$, and for every constant symbol $c$, $c = x_1$ is definable by an $L'$-formula $\psi_c(x_1)$.

Let $T'$ be the $L'$-theory obtained by replacing all symbols in $L\setminus L'$ in the sentences of $T$ by their definitions. Then $T$ is a definitional expansion of $T'$, i.e. if we extend $T'$ by the definitions of all the symbols in $L\setminus L'$, the resulting theory is equivalent to $T$.

Comment: as always thanks so much for the thorough response, this clears a lot of things up for me. the topological proof of your lemma is very slick, but unfortunately I think I'm still missing something – why isn't it guilty of the same flaw as in my argument? in particular, if I'm understanding correctly, your argument shows that, for any $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\psi$, there is a finite boolean combination $\theta$ of the desired formulas such that $[\psi]=[\theta]\in S_n(T)$. but doesn't this again show only that $\psi$ and $\theta$ are equivalent modulo $T$, and not equivalent in general?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yes, sorry. It should say equivalent modulo $T$!